# Picture in one column causes text to be pushed down in the column next to it

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Not that good at programming, but

The picture causes the text to move down on the adjacent column and I have no idea why this is happening. I've tried floating it and using vertical alignment, neither work.

```
<table style="border:none" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
       <tr>
       <td vertical-align:baseline style="border:none" width="20%">
       <div><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-232" src="" style="float:left;border: 1px solid #000000; alt="" width="294" height="300" style="display:block;"></div>
       <div class="caption" style="font:8pt/12pt verdana" align="center">text</div>
       </td>
       <td style="border:none;float:right" style="border:none">
       <div style="font:10pt/14pt verdana" align="justify">text</div>
       </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Any particular reason to use inline CSS instead of proper stylesheets?

Comment: I have no idea how stylesheets work

Comment: Just an external file linked by `<link rel="stylesheet" src="...">` with contents like `table{border:none}` `td.col-2 {border:none; float: right; /*floating TDs???*/}` (just with more linebreaks). Look up a decent CSS tutorial

Answer (score 2):

```
<td vertical-align:baseline style="border:none" width="20%">
```

That is not correct syntax. Try:

```
<td style="border:none; vertical-align:baseline" width="20%">
```

Also, this:

```
style="float:left;border: 1px solid #000000; alt="" width="294" height="300" style="display:block;"
```

is missing a quote and has `style` twice. Try:

```
style="float:left;border: 1px solid #000000; display:block;" alt=""
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Unfortunately these fixes did not correct the misalignment.

Comment: @user1989134 you cannot expect "full" answers on "fix my code" questions - one never knows when he's done.

Comment: @user1989134 there's a second `<td>` with two style attributes. I leae it up to you to find it.

Comment: Well I have fixed the things that you pointed out were wrong. Is there any way to fix this without CSS or stylesheets?

Answer (score 1):

There are many tags missing in your code.There is no closing tag of tr and many like this.

Change it to the below method

**HTML**

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
       <tr>
       <td width="50%">     
         <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-232" src="" alt="" width="294" height="300" />
       <div class="caption">text</div>
       </td>
       <td class="second_td">text</td>
</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.caption{display:inline-block; font:8pt/12pt verdana;}
.second_td{font:10pt/14pt verdana; vertical-align:top; text-align:right}
img{float:left;border: 1px solid #000000;}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wLGsy/1/)**

Comment: Unclosed `<td>`s and `<tr>`s are valid HTML (sadly).

Comment: Unclosed `p`s are valid as well. since you can't nest `p`s, they auto-close their previous occurence.

Comment: Ever heard the words "tag soup"? Sooo accurate :-)